Is ὁδηγήσει in John 16:13 necessarily personal?
John 16:13 is translated as:

However, δὲ (de) when ὅταν (hotan) the τὸ (to) Spirit Πνεῦμα (Pneuma) of truth ἀληθείας (alētheias) comes ἔλθῃ (elthē) He will guide ὁδηγήσει (hodēgēsei) you ὑμᾶς (hymas) into ἐν (en) all πάσῃ (pasē) truth. ἀληθείᾳ (alētheia) For γὰρ (gar) He will not speak
λαλήσει (lalēsei) on ἀφ’ (aph’) His own, ἑαυτοῦ (heautou) but ἀλλ’ (all’)
He will speak λαλήσει (lalēsei) what ὅσα (hosa) He hears, ἀκούσει (akousei)
and καὶ (kai) He will declare ἀναγγελεῖ (anangelei) to you ὑμῖν (hymin)
what is τὰ (ta) to come. ἐρχόμενα (erchomena) Bible Hub
However, when the Spirit of truth comes, He will guide you into all truth. For He will not speak on His own, but He will speak what He hears, and He will declare to you what is to come.


ὁδηγήσει (hodēgēsei)
Verb - Future Indicative Active - 3rd Person Singular
Strong's 3594: To lead, guide; met: I instruct, teach. From hodegos;
to show the way (teach).


Dictionary:  ὁδηγέω
Greek transliteration:  hodēgeō
Simplified transliteration:  hodegeo Principal Parts:  ὁδηγήσω, -, -,
-, - Numbers
Gloss:  to lead, guide; explain, instruct
Definition:  to lead, guide, Mt. 15:14; Lk. 6:39; Rev. 7:17; met. to
instruct, teach, Jn. 16:13; Acts 8:31


The third-person subjective singular pronouns are "he," "she," and
"it." The third-person objective singular pronouns are "him," "her,"
and "it." Here are a few examples of third-person singular pronouns
used in sentences, with the personal pronouns in italics for
reference: "Ginny hurried to work on Monday morning.

Is ὁδηγήσει (hodēgēsei) in John 16:13 necessarily personal?


Note: After this question was answered, I learned the Bible Hub Greek is not accurate, that:

The Greek is ὅταν δὲ ἔλθῃ ἐκεῖνος, τὸ Πνεῦμα τῆς ἀληθείας, ὁδηγήσει ὑμᾶς εἰς τὴν ἀλήθειαν πᾶσαν· οὐ γὰρ λαλήσει ἀφ’ ἑαυτοῦ, ἀλλ’ ὅσα ἀκούει λαλήσει, καὶ τὰ ἐρχόμενα ἀναγγελεῖ ὑμῖν. Nestle Greek New Testament 1904

13 οταν δε ελθη εκεινοϲ · το πνα τηϲ αληθιαϲ · οδηγηϲει υμαϲ εν τη αληθεια ┬ · ου γαρ λαληϲει αφ εαυτου · αλλʼ οϲἁ ακουει λαληϲει . και τα ερχομενα αναγγελλει ημιν : 14 εκεινοϲ εμε δοξαϲει · οτι εκ του εμου λημψεται · κ(αι) αναγγελλει ϋμιν Codex Sinaiticus

Bible Hub has the word ἐκεῖνος (ekeinos) only in John 16:14



The last quotation seems to be cut off, and that and one of the other quotations don't have any citation.

The Greek of John 16:13 is particularly simple to translate.  Here is my very translation showing the sentence structure.

However, when He shall come, the Spirit of the Truth,

[He] will guide you into all truth
[He] will not speak for Himself
but whatever [He] may hear [He] will speak
and the things coming [He] will declare to you


Let us observe several things about the grammar of this sentence:

There are two explicit pronouns: "He" which is the first of those highlighted above.  This pronoun is ἐκεῖνος (ekeinos) which is the demonstrative pronoun and is masculine, meaning that technically, it should be translated, "that person, He!" The second explicit pronoun is discussed in #3 below.
The remaining [bracketed] "He" pronouns are implied because all the subsequent dependent clauses with their verbs have as their subject, "He, the Spirit of the Truth".  These subsequent verbs include: ὁδηγήσει (He will guide); λαλήσει (He will speak); ἀκούσει (He will hear); ἀναγγελεῖ (He will declare).
This is further reinforced by the use of the masculine reflexive pronoun, ἑαυτοῦ = "Himself" in the second dependent clause above.
The phrase "the Sprit of the Truth" (literally) is in apposition to the demonstrative masculine pronoun "He", leaving no doubt about the identity of the subject of the sentence and that John is discussing a personal being, viz, the Holy Spirit.

Therefore, the answer to the OP's question is that these verbs have as their subject the personal demonstrative pronoun, "He", which refers directly to:

The Spirit of Truth - a title used exclusively for the Holy Spirit, John 14:17, 15:26, 16:13, 1 John 4:6
The Advocate or parakletos in John 14:16, 26, 15:26, 16:7 - the last of which is the subject of the subsequent discussion including V13.

Now, in writing John 16:13, the Holy Spirit inspired John to write the sentence in the peculiar way we have it to show that the Holy Spirit is indeed very personal.

Why would it be grammatically wrong to translate it as
"However, when it shall come, the spirit of truth,
it will guide you into all truth.
It will not speak for itself,
but whatever it may hear it will speak,
and the things coming, it will declare to you."?
(It all depends on the very first "He/it".)

@RayButterworth - because, the subject of the sentence is the masculine demonstrative pronoun ἐκεῖνος, reinforced by the masculine reflexive pronoun, ἑαυτοῦ.  This is further reinforced by the subject of this section of John 16 which is parakletos ("Advocate") - also masculine.

@RayButterworth - in fact, the sentence would make perfect sense if the masculine demonstrative pronoun were omitted giving, "When the spirit of truth comes ..."  Under these circumstances, your translation above might be allowable.

@Dottard. Thank you for your answer. I was reading John 16:13 in Bible Hub, which appears to use a different Greek text to you & others. In Bible Hub, it appears  ἐκεῖνος (ekeinos) is found in John 16:14 rather than John 16:13. Regards

@Dottard thank you again for your answer. However, i am not fluent with grammar. The word Holy Spirit is neutral. The word 'kingdom' is feminine. The words 'heaven' & 'God' are masculine. Therefore the terms Kingdom of Heaven/God contain both feminine & masculine words. At this link https://biblehub.com/greek/ekeine__1565.htm  there are examples of the feminine ἐκεῖνος often translated as "that" therefore i guess this feminine personal pronoun when applied to things such as "kingdom", "city" & "house" follows the gender of those nouns.

Therefore can you kindly explain why Holy Spirit would be neutral yet use the masculine  ἐκεῖνος  as a pronoun? Thanks. I note "Advocate" is masculine and "Spirit Of Truth" is all feminine. Possibly this feminine case follows pre-Christian traditional gender.

@Dhammadhatu - actually we have all three. In the phrase “He the Spirit of Truth”, “he” is masculine, “Spirit” is neuter, and “truth” is feminine. However, the grammatical subject remains “He”.

@Dhammadhatu ἐκεῖνος is in John 16:13 on the Bible Hub site. It would appear the masculine pronoun was used to make the point: it is personal.

i can't see it: https://biblehub.com/john/16-13.htm#lexicon

@Dhammadhatu - fourth word here  https://biblehub.com/interlinear/john/16-13.htm

Thank you for this. Its obviously better than what i have been looking at. Bible Hub is an easy site to use.
